# Сломался Мавен. Can't find Maven installation

Tags: maven, веб-программирование, сборка, java

А конкретнее так
Can't find Maven installation D:\Soft\apache-maven-3.0.5

[image]

Происходит это когда я пытаюсь сделать Build, но в тоже время Clean нормально работает. (Речь идет о плагине для еклипса) Я удалил его и поставил снова, та же проблема. С консоли нормально распознает мавен, все как положено. Что можно сделать? Нет, конечно я мог поменять eclipse(с большой вероятностью это поможет) но это будет сильно костыльно. Буду рад услышать ваши варианты. Если нужны доп.данные, напишите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная среды `MAVEN_HOME` живая?